# Is this union compatible with strict-aliasing rules?

Tags: c++11, unions, strict-aliasing

Is it OK to use both parts of a union if you know the parts don't overlap?  Like in this example, is it OK to use both buf[31] as well as ps?

```
struct PtrSize {
  const char *data;
  size_t size;
};

class SmallStringOrNot {
  union {
    PtrSize  ps;
    char     buf[32];
  } pb;

public:
  bool IsSmallString() const {
    return pb.buf[31] != 0;
  }
  SmallStringOrNot(const char *str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if (len && len < 31) {
      memcpy(pb.buf, str, len);
      pb.buf[31] = len;
    } else {
      pb.ps.data = str;
      pb.ps.size = len;
      pb.buf[31] = 0;    // is this OK, accessing buf right after ps?
    }
  }
  PtrSize AsPtrSize() const {
    if (IsSmallString()) {
      return PtrSize{pb.buf, pb.buf[31]};
    } else {
      return pb.ps;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the code is not OK: you are at least not in "undefined behaviour"-zone, since in C++ it is always legal to access a `union` through a `char` member, but you have no guarantee that by modifying `buf[31]` you are not altering `ps.data` or `ps.size`. In a 128-bit machine you would almost surely be doing it.

On more normal architectures, your code should be fine but for a 100% guarantee you should refer to the compiler documentation, since `size_t` could in principle be bigger than a `void*`. For example, even on a 64-bit machine you could theoretically have a 192-bit `ps.size` member  (which summed with the 64 bit of the `ps.data` pointer would make the `PtrSize` completely overlap the buffer.

Comment: Hmmm, OK assuming that I add a compile-time assert that the size of buf is larger than the size of PtrSize, would I be OK?